# RecyclerView: last item's animation on notifyItemRemoved()

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

Behaviour's video: (no longer available)

**Removing:**

```
viewHolder.buttonDelete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        mItemManger.removeShownLayouts(viewHolder.swipeLayout);
        mDataset.remove(position);
        notifyItemRemoved(position);
        notifyItemRangeChanged(position, mDataset.size());
        mItemManger.closeAllItems();
        Toast.makeText(view.getContext(), "Deleted " + viewHolder.textViewPos.getText().toString() + "!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
});
```

How can I fix this?

**Notes:**
I'm using [this library](https://github.com/daimajia/AndroidSwipeLayout), and I have  the libraries updated.

**Update:**

```
viewHolder.buttonDelete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        mItemManger.removeShownLayouts(viewHolder.swipeLayout);
        mResultArray.remove(position);
        notifyItemRangeChanged(position, mResultArray.size());
        notifyItemRemoved(position);
        mItemManger.closeAllItems();
        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        }, 500);
    }
});
```

Comment: How have you solved the problem? I have the same issue, tried the solution from the accepted answer, the same result (

Comment: I edited with the current working code, I'm not sure if it will solve the issue tho

Comment: @JohnSardinha the "Behaviour's video" link (`vid . me / nF1J`) is redirecting to an adult website.

Comment: @Marino thanks, I've removed it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you should call `notifyItemRangeRemoved(position, 1);` instead.

Comment: That made the items bellow disappear and appear, looks weird

Comment: Looks differently weird, when the first item isnt shown, and I delete one, the items above move down

Comment: i will let u know if i found a better solution

Answer (score 12):

RecyclerView must have `layout_height="match_parent"`. Had the same issue with the last item disappearing and reappearing driving me crazy.

Comment: This was exactly my problem. Thanks!